# Reactive Vue JS global variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, user-controls, global-variables, vue-data

In Vue JS I'm getting a user back from a sign in request and the response looks something like this

```
{
user: {
id: 1,
email: "user@gmail.com",
password: [filtered],
role: admin
}
}
```

How can I save this user in a variable that I can access anywhere in the Vue JS app meaning any component? My sign in code is below:

```
signinSuccesful(response){
            if(!response.data.csrf){
                this.signinFailed(response)
                return
            }

            localStorage.csrf = response.data.csrf
            localStorage.signedIn = true
            this.user = response.data.user
            this.error = ''
            this.$router.replace('/')
        }
```

I have tried globalProperties but they are not reactive

```
app.config.globalProperties.$currentUser = {}
```

And another Issue that I have found is that by passing the data into child components and also passing a method to update it too works initially but the data is changed back(is lost) after refresh.

Comment: "but the data is changed back(is lost) after refresh" - what did you try and what do you mean by refresh?

Comment: I mean when the page is refreshed or routes change.

Comment: These are two different conditions that need to be addressed differently. You likely need global store. And in order to persist page refresh, you need to sync it with localstorage. Existing stores like Vuex and Pinia have persistence plugins that don't require to implement this yourself